# Error regarding invalid file permissions for upgrading WordPress version

Tags: errors, localhost, upgrade, local-installation

I recently installed wordpress and am working with it locally. The WordPress folder is at the following path: **usr/share/wordpress**

But the version of WordPress is WordPress 4.9.5 and I want to update it to the latest version: **WordPress 5.6.1.**

**Following is the error I am receiving:** [image: Error image]

**Error text:** The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-includes/class-smtp.php, wp-includes/ID3/module.tag.lyrics3.php................

After a Google search and following several links, the error is not resolved.
The last command I ran (from **usr/share/wordpress**) is this

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *
```

My current directory and file permissions are as follows:
[image: permissions]

How do I resolve this error ?

Comment: What user is PHP running as? (If you can't answer that: how did you install PHP and a webserver?)

Comment: I used the steps mentioned here https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview